# How to show the xsl-foreach data on single fo:table-cell?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am having an xml file to filter the data using xsl-fo templating language. My XML:

```
 <root>
<name>shyam</name>
<friend>
    <name>Abc</name>
    <phNo>90909090909</phNo>
    <age>32</age>
    <closefriends>
        <names>test123</names>
    </closefriends>
</friend>
<friend>
    <name>Xyz</name>
    <phNo>32323232323</phNo>
    <age>44</age>
    <closefriends>
        <names>test345</names>
    </closefriends>
</friend>
</root>
```

I wanted to fetch the name and names values and show it on the some table-cell in xsl-fo template.

My XSL-FO template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

```
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block>Hello,
          <xsl:value-of select="name" />!</fo:block>
        <fo:block>
          <fo:table>
            <fo:table-body>
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>
                    No.
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>
                    Name
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center" font-weight="bold">
                  <fo:block>
                    Phone Number
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
              <xsl:for-each select="./friend">
                <xsl:for-each select="./closefriends">
                  <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="names" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border="solid 1px black" text-align="center">
                      <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="phNo" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

I am unable to fetch the name value, getting only closefriends-->names. Need to get the name and as well as names on same table td.

Appreciate for any help..thanks

Comment: Instead of `select="./friend"`, you can drop the `./` and just do `select="friend"`.  Similarly for `./closefriends`.  The long explanation is that both are evaluated relative to the context node, but `./friend` is shorthand for `self::node()/child::friend` and `friend` is shorthand for `child::friend`.  The extra `self::node()` doesn't add anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of `<xsl:value-of select="name" />` you need to select the parent's name with `<xsl:value-of select="../name" />`.